# Load PKCS#8 binary key into Ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl, pkcs#8

I'm trying to load a particular private key encoded in binary `DER` format (`PKCS#8`) into Ruby.

However, `OpenSSL::PKey` won't recognize it. I can make it work by doing some console work and transforming it into a `PEM` like so:

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -passin pass:xxxxxxxx >private_key.pem
```

After this, the key can correctly be read.

However, since I would like for the whole process to be done in memory instead of writing and reading files.

So my question is: Is it possible to load private keys from the binary encoded `DER` format into Ruby/OpenSSL?

Thank you for your time,

Fernando

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can *indirectly* load PKCS#8 DER-encoded private keys using Ruby OpenSSL.

`OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new` will only handle PEM-formatted PKCS#8, but it is easy to read the binary DER and convert it to a PEM-formatted string and then load from the string.

For example, with these DER-encoded private keys:

```
$ openssl genrsa | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER \
    -nocrypt -out pkcs8.key
$ openssl genrsa | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER \
    -v2 des3 -passout pass:secret -out pkcs8_des3.key
```

You can do something like this:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def box(tag, lines)
  lines.unshift "-----BEGIN #{tag}-----"
  lines.push "-----END #{tag}-----"
  lines.join("\n")
end

def der_to_pem(tag, der)
  box tag, Base64.strict_encode64(der).scan(/.{1,64}/)
end

pem = der_to_pem('PRIVATE KEY', File.read('pkcs8.key'))
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem)

pem2 = der_to_pem('ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY', File.read('pkcs8_des3.key'))
key2 = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem2, 'secret')
```

Read the DER bytes, Base64 them and put the PEM tags on top and bottom, and then load the key.

Answer (score 0):

> Certificate is capable of handling DER-encoded certificates and certificates encoded in OpenSSL's PEM format.

You could find documentation about OpenSSL implementation for Ruby [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html) :

Comment: That is incorrect. For PEM, the Ruby source calls PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey, which calls PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey, which yes, handles PKCS#8. However, when DER, the Ruby source calls d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio, which calls ASN1_item_i2d_bio(ASN1_ITEM_rptr(RSAPrivateKey), bp, rsa) (openssl-1.0.1m/crypto/rsa/rsa_asn1.c: ASN1_SEQUENCE_cb(RSAPrivateKey, rsa_cb) = { ASN1_SIMPLE(RSA, version, LONG), ...) which will *not* read PKCS#8. DER-encoded PKCS#8 *cannot* be loaded directly using OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new.

Comment: My bad. I didnt know that the implementation of OpenSSL in ruby was different than what is said in the OpenSSL documentation...