# RAILS - Decrypt PKCS8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption

How can I do this on RoR but getting only pem string.

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -passin pass:xxxxxxxx >private_key.pem
```

I alredy try this solution: [Load PKCS#8 binary key into Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753184/load-pkcs8-binary-key-into-ruby)

But RSA.new returns me **Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error**

The Ruby Code:

```
def get_pem(key_file, passphrase)
 pem = der_to_pem('PRIVATE KEY', File.read(key_file))
 key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem, passphrase)
end

def box(tag, lines)
  lines.unshift "-----BEGIN #{tag}-----"
  lines.push "-----END #{tag}-----"
  lines.join("\n")
end

def der_to_pem(tag, der)
  box tag, Base64.strict_encode64(der).scan(/.{1,64}/)
end
```

Here the outputs on each function before call openssl tool:

Function: der_to_pem
tag: PRIVATE KEY
der:

```
0\x82\u0002\xC60@\u0006\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\u0001\u0005\r030\e\u0006\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\u0001\u0005\f0\u000E\u0004\b\u0002\u0001\u0000\u0002\x81\x81\u0000\xA4\u0002\u0002\u0004\u00000\u0014\u0006\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\u0003\a\u0004\b0\x82\u0002v\u0002\u0001\u00000\u0004\x82\u0002\x80\xFE[J\x92\xED˺\xA5u*V\xBD\xF10\vߝ\xF4\xEF\x99\xD63<xׇ\x82\u0001㙶\xB7\xAE\x88J\u001C\xCFi\n\xCD\xCE?*\xCBPD\r\xAA+G\xFB\u00180~2</\x9E\x8C\x87\xE6?ꋹ@\xB1\xB0\u0590H\xF2\xDC\xF5F$\xA4\xC3\xF9䳹\u007F{*\xE0\"\x9C\x82\x82\f)T\u001C\x84\xE7\xEFQl\xC5\xCF^\x91\xC65\x88\x92\f\u0019n\xC7y\xB4|\xA3`\xC0\x8C\xC1\x96S7Nf\xC5\xD0\r\xFA\xBFG\u0015\xB1\x81\xF5p%\u0012T2\x95\xFE2Z\xD7\xED\xE12\u0001\a\xACN\xA6#\xBE\x94\xA1\x97'<\x9C\xB2ҾI\xF1io\xBF\xD1\xE0\xB6\u001A\u0010o\u0015\xEB'F~\xAC\xC3eG\xBF\xF2\x84\x88\xD9\u001C\u000E\xED\u0013s\x91jTnU\u0379[\x9C?\xB3ܮ\xD4\u0016n\xAE?\xD0\u0001\xB0\u0016)SMd\xF2\u0002q\xBB\xC5;\x83\u0019+\x90\u0018\u007Fܳ\xA4\xC4\u001Cs\xFA\u0013\xA1\xA3;d\ekUT\x98/wd\u001E\x9Er\xD4\u0002\xE6\xEBB'$\u0014\xBF\b\xF3\xDC\xCFe,;\x97\x9CӒ\xC1\u0000\x9F\xFDu#\xA4\u007F\r\u0016D 1\xEA\f^\xD0ű\r'ܝ\xDF\xF7\xCE\xCE+{\x96^ь\b_\u0012\xDC\xD8x9}\u0005Rq\xB9\xCC\xFE\xFEvd\xB7\u00108\xC8\xE1\xE5\xD4\xC4i\x9D\xDA(\u0005[\xC0_t\xF5\e\u0018\xBB\u001D\xEC\xAE\xC7\xE8\x8A(\x90w\xCF\xFEcl[\xC2\a3\xB2 ~^\xC4\u001D\u000F\xACl\u0011M\xE4\xA1\xF2Y\u0004o,\xAEl\xC1\u000F$\u0013qSc\x99\u001A\xD2$|\xBC\xAB\x90\xE7\xF0\xF7f\xDFȿ\u0016;lA_\x85\xCA\u000F\x9B#~d\xF2\x9C\u0013*\xA9=Jl\x81t\x85\x96*l\xA8(kt\xD4\u0019\xB4\xB8\u0001U7\xEC\xE9.#;\xA0\u000F\u0003\x91\u0004-\n/P\xDC\xCC\u001A\xA5\xDD\xDA\xE4\u001F\xF2\\\xF1ʗ,E\"0\x93\xD7\xD9\xD1\u001F\x84G_C\xCC\xC23~\xBDC\xA7ab\xBD\xBC\x83ʱ\xE3\xE0\x8F ^\xC0\xDF~\xB5\xBAT\xE8ގ\xFE\xC3\xE5\xCF\xEB\xAC\xE3|n\x8B\u000E&%ʍqk\xAD=\x86\u0005\xD4\xD9+\xF4\xA6\u0000d!\x95b\xEDuY\xAE\xE5jG0\x85\xDE\"\xADc\xACK\x833\xA5lP#\u0000=G\xB3\xCE\xF6\xC0[ԙU\xD5\e:{\u00100\x9B{\x95\x9C@ \xB3\x86\xC2@S\u0015~p؛\u0013\xF48[\xBE\b\e\u007F\xD7x)\u0010\xD7\u001A\xDE\xF2\x9E\xA5X\x8A\u007FV\xF3\xECޱ\xC9\acl\u0004B\x8F\xD3c\x80\xE1\u0016BI\xED\xAA}
```

der(base64):

Function: box
lines:

```
0\x82\u0002\xC60@\u0006\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\u0001\u0005\r030\e\u0006\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\u0001\u0005\f0\u000E\u0004\b\u0002\u0001\u0000\u0002\x81\x81\u0000\xA4\u0002\u0002\u0004\u00000\u0014\u0006\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\u0003\a\u0004\b0\x82\u0002v\u0002\u0001\u00000\u0004\x82\u0002\x80\xFE[J\x92\xED˺\xA5u*V\xBD\xF10\vߝ\xF4\xEF\x99\xD63<xׇ\x82\u0001㙶\xB7\xAE\x88J\u001C\xCFi\n\xCD\xCE?*\xCBPD\r\xAA+G\xFB\u00180~2</\x9E\x8C\x87\xE6?ꋹ@\xB1\xB0\u0590H\xF2\xDC\xF5F$\xA4\xC3\xF9䳹\u007F{*\xE0\"\x9C\x82\x82\f)T\u001C\x84\xE7\xEFQl\xC5\xCF^\x91\xC65\x88\x92\f\u0019n\xC7y\xB4|\xA3`\xC0\x8C\xC1\x96S7Nf\xC5\xD0\r\xFA\xBFG\u0015\xB1\x81\xF5p%\u0012T2\x95\xFE2Z\xD7\xED\xE12\u0001\a\xACN\xA6#\xBE\x94\xA1\x97'<\x9C\xB2ҾI\xF1io\xBF\xD1\xE0\xB6\u001A\u0010o\u0015\xEB'F~\xAC\xC3eG\xBF\xF2\x84\x88\xD9\u001C\u000E\xED\u0013s\x91jTnU\u0379[\x9C?\xB3ܮ\xD4\u0016n\xAE?\xD0\u0001\xB0\u0016)SMd\xF2\u0002q\xBB\xC5;\x83\u0019+\x90\u0018\u007Fܳ\xA4\xC4\u001Cs\xFA\u0013\xA1\xA3;d\ekUT\x98/wd\u001E\x9Er\xD4\u0002\xE6\xEBB'$\u0014\xBF\b\xF3\xDC\xCFe,;\x97\x9CӒ\xC1\u0000\x9F\xFDu#\xA4\u007F\r\u0016D 1\xEA\f^\xD0ű\r'ܝ\xDF\xF7\xCE\xCE+{\x96^ь\b_\u0012\xDC\xD8x9}\u0005Rq\xB9\xCC\xFE\xFEvd\xB7\u00108\xC8\xE1\xE5\xD4\xC4i\x9D\xDA(\u0005[\xC0_t\xF5\e\u0018\xBB\u001D\xEC\xAE\xC7\xE8\x8A(\x90w\xCF\xFEcl[\xC2\a3\xB2 ~^\xC4\u001D\u000F\xACl\u0011M\xE4\xA1\xF2Y\u0004o,\xAEl\xC1\u000F$\u0013qSc\x99\u001A\xD2$|\xBC\xAB\x90\xE7\xF0\xF7f\xDFȿ\u0016;lA_\x85\xCA\u000F\x9B#~d\xF2\x9C\u0013*\xA9=Jl\x81t\x85\x96*l\xA8(kt\xD4\u0019\xB4\xB8\u0001U7\xEC\xE9.#;\xA0\u000F\u0003\x91\u0004-\n/P\xDC\xCC\u001A\xA5\xDD\xDA\xE4\u001F\xF2\\\xF1ʗ,E\"0\x93\xD7\xD9\xD1\u001F\x84G_C\xCC\xC23~\xBDC\xA7ab\xBD\xBC\x83ʱ\xE3\xE0\x8F ^\xC0\xDF~\xB5\xBAT\xE8ގ\xFE\xC3\xE5\xCF\xEB\xAC\xE3|n\x8B\u000E&%ʍqk\xAD=\x86\u0005\xD4\xD9+\xF4\xA6\u0000d!\x95b\xEDuY\xAE\xE5jG0\x85\xDE\"\xADc\xACK\x833\xA5lP#\u0000=G\xB3\xCE\xF6\xC0[ԙU\xD5\e:{\u00100\x9B{\x95\x9C@ \xB3\x86\xC2@S\u0015~p؛\u0013\xF48[\xBE\b\e\u007F\xD7x)\u0010\xD7\u001A\xDE\xF2\x9E\xA5X\x8A\u007FV\xF3\xECޱ\xC9\acl\u0004B\x8F\xD3c\x80\xE1\u0016BI\xED\xAA}
```

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIICxjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIAgEAAoGBAKQCAgQA
>   MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAgwggJ2AgEAMASCAoD+W0qS7cu6pXUqVr3xMAvfnfTvmdYz
>   PHjXh4IB45m2t66IShzPaQrNzj8qy1BEDaorR/sYMH4yPC+ejIfmP+qLuUCxsNaQ
>   SPLc9UYkpMP55LO5f3sq4CKcgoIMKVQchOfvUWzFz16RxjWIkgwZbsd5tHyjYMCM
>   wZZTN05mxdAN+r9HFbGB9XAlElQylf4yWtft4TIBB6xOpiO+lKGXJzycstK+SfFp
>   b7/R4LYaEG8V6ydGfqzDZUe/8oSI2RwO7RNzkWpUblXNuVucP7PcrtQWbq4/0AGw
>   FilTTWTyAnG7xTuDGSuQGH/cs6TEHHP6E6GjO2Qba1VUmC93ZB6ectQC5utCJyQU
>   vwjz3M9lLDuXnNOSwQCf/XUjpH8NFkQgMeoMXtDFsQ0n3J3f987OK3uWXtGMCF8S
>   3Nh4OX0FUnG5zP7+dmS3EDjI4eXUxGmd2igFW8BfdPUbGLsd7K7H6IookHfP/mNs
>   W8IHM7Igfl7EHQ+sbBFN5KHyWQRvLK5swQ8kE3FTY5ka0iR8vKuQ5/D3Zt/IvxY7
>   bEFfhcoPmyN+ZPKcEyqpPUpsgXSFlipsqChrdNQZtLgBVTfs6S4jO6APA5EELQov
>   UNzMGqXd2uQf8lzxypcsRSIwk9fZ0R+ER19DzMIzfr1Dp2FivbyDyrHj4I8gXsDf
>   frW6VOjejv7D5c/rrON8bosOJiXKjXFrrT2GBdTZK/Sm7p6jAGQhlWLtdVmu5WpH
>   MIXeIq1jrEuDM6VsUCMAPUezzvbAW9SZVdUbOnsQMJt7lZxAILOGwkBTFX5w2JsT
>   9Dhbvggbf9d4KRDXGt7ynqVYin9W8+zesckHY2wEQo/TY4DhFkJJ7ap9
>   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: What does your Ruby code look like?

Comment: Sorry i forget it.

Comment: My immediate suspicion is that `der_to_pem` function. Does the output of that verify with the `openssl` tool? It's easy to get these things ever so slightly wrong.

Comment: der_to_pem function just take the binary string of file.key decode on base64, box function adds the begin and end tags, do u want see the string before call openssl tool?

Comment: I'm just curious if that validates properly. You'll need to be sure each step you have here produces the correct output.

Comment: ohh ok, ahm, how can I know the correct outputs on each step?

Comment: Minimal approach is to just `puts` out what you're doing, maybe cut and paste that into individual files and test it. A more involved method might be to write out that string into a file using `File.open('test.key', 'w')` and do it formally in Ruby if you're feeling up to the task.

Comment: ok, let's me do that. ty

Comment: ok, there are the outputs for each function.