# Ruby OpenSSL pkcs8 .key to .pem

Tags: ruby, openssl

We run this command via Gem.

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file_init.key -passin pass:secret -out file_key.pem
```

All works fine on shell, we wanna convert this line to openssl with ruby, we tried:

```
key_file = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read('file_init'), 'secret'
puts key_file.to_pem_pkcs8
```

But we get:

```
`initialize': Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load PKCS#8 binary key into Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753184/load-pkcs8-binary-key-into-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's openssl implementation doesn't handle pkcs8 encrypted der key-file.
There is a workaround (converting the der to PEM by base64 encoding the der + adding correct headers) here:
[Load PKCS#8 binary key into Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753184/load-pkcs8-binary-key-into-ruby)