# Decrypt PKCS#8 Ruby OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, pkcs#8

I need to use the OpenSSL ruby gem to decrypt a file. I've tried what every post told me to do. I've tried using this code from: [Load PKCS#8 binary key into Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753184/load-pkcs8-binary-key-into-ruby)

```
  def box(tag, lines)
    lines.unshift "-----BEGIN #{tag}-----"
    lines.push "-----END #{tag}-----"
    lines.join("\n")
  end

  def der_to_pem(tag, der)
    box tag, Base64.strict_encode64(der).scan(/.{1,64}/)
  end

  pem = der_to_pementer code here('ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY', File.read('./file.key'))
  key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem, 'passkey')
  puts key 
  puts pem
```

And I get this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAzxy...
...ECYUOVC3zgw23aGcFA8z9ghI=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFDjBABgk...
...Y948X9Zop7aCnxmWI7vHNts=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I need something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADA...
...ZwUDzP2CEg==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is the console code that works, but as I said I need to use the ruby gem:

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in "./file.key" -passin pass:passkey -out "./file.key.pem"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to decrypt on PKCS#8 format by `openssl` gem. But there are some hacky ways.

1. Execute the OpenSSL command from ruby.
2. Install the following gem (https://github.com/twg/openssl_pkcs8)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having troubles installing that gem, I think I'll have to execute the command. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @EstebanArochaOrtuño If you don't mind, would you accept my answer?