# How to create pfx using openSSL with .cer file and PKCS#8 encrypted private key

Tags: openssl

Trying to use below command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.cer -inkey cert.key -out cert.pfx
```

I'm seeing unable to load private key exception. openssl is expecting private key.

Private key in my case is pkcs#8 encrypted. I have password for encrypted private key. But openssl is not prompting for password.

I did made progress to convert private key to privatekey.pem using below command. I did find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753184/load-pkcs8-binary-key-into-ruby)

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -passin pass:xxxxxxxx >private_key.pem
```

Comment: That command should work fine.  So the problem is either with the private key or with the cer file, what are the error messages out of openssl.  Can you verify the private key is ok and the cert file is ok with openssl?  e.g. "openssl rsa -in cert.key -noout -text"  The verification of the cert file will depend of the format. e.g. pem would be "openssl x509 -in cert.cer -noout -text".

Comment: I tried above eg "openssl rsa -in cert.key -noout -text" it says unable to load private key and for certificate it says error as unable to load certificate. errorcode: 0009006C pem routines: get_name: no start

Comment: _Look at_ the contents of cert.cer. Is it actually a cert in PEM format? Is it something else in PEM format? Is it not in PEM format at all? Describe it, or if not human-readable post a hex or similar dump of at least about the first 16 bytes.

Comment: PEM format is a base64 DER format with markup.  So it's a text file you can open in a text editor.  If it's binary, it's most like DER format.  Try "openssl rsa -in cert.key -inform der -noout -text" and see it that works.  If it's in DER format you need to convert it to PEM format for the pscs12 command to work.

Comment: Convert key from der to pem: openssl rsa -in cert.key -inform der -out cert.key.pem

Comment: In my case both certificate and key are not in a human readable format. I was able to convert both Key and Certificate to pem files and then later converted to pfx using pem files. I will post an answer with commands I used.

Answer (score 2):

Below are commands I used to convert to Pfx.

Converted certificate to pem

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

converted key to pem

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -passin pass:xxxxxxxx >private_key.pem
```

converted to pfx using above key and certificate pem files. I need to use csp for my case. But it is optional.

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey private_key.pem -CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -out cert.pfx
```